# How to have duration.years and duration.month in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Hello currently I display a timer with two digit ( DD HH mm SS)

I would like to display a new timer like ( YY MM DD HH)

Here is my current code

```
 String _formatDuration_conso(Duration duration) {
    String twoDigits(int n) {
      if (n >= 10) return "$n";
      return "0$n";
    }
   
    String twoDigitHours = twoDigits(duration.inHours.remainder(24));
    String twoDigitMinutes = twoDigits(duration.inMinutes.remainder(60));
    String twoDigitSeconds = twoDigits(duration.inSeconds.remainder(60));
    return "${twoDigits(duration.inDays)}   $twoDigitHours   $twoDigitMinutes   $twoDigitSeconds";
  }
```

Thank you

Comment: Your question is impossible to answer if you have only a Duration.  Quick... where is the cutoff for "2 months"?  59, 60, 61, or 62 days?  (Depends on the start day.) So it makes some sense only if it's two DateTime where you can make some educated input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert days into years

```
  int inYears(int days) {
    if (days < 1) return 0;

    return days~/365;
  }
```

and then

```
   String _formatDuration_conso(Duration duration) {
    //..
    return "${twoDigits(inYears(duration.inDays))}   ${twoDigits(duration.inDays)}   $twoDigitHours   $twoDigitMinutes   $twoDigitSeconds";
  }
```